# Two column layout with one having a fixed width in CSS

Tags: css, layout

I want a nice 2 column layout using CSS float's.

Column#1 160 px
Column#2 100% (i.e. the rest of the space).

I want to place the Col#2's div first, so my layout looks like:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
     <div id="col2"></div>
     <div id="col1"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

What has to be get this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above will work.

```css
div#col2 {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

div#col1 {
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 160px;
}
```

That's assuming that Column 2 should appear as a left sidebar, with col 1 as the main content.

Comment: I think it's the other way around.

Comment: Remember that when you refer to other questions, they aren't "above" or below, because as they collect votes, the order of questions changes. Use a quote from the answers, or avoid the phrasing altogether: if you say "bob's answer" well, they might answer AGAIN after yours.

Comment: This is the answer but mabwi needs to exchange #col1 <-> #col2. Voted up in anticipation of the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "float" CSS property for doing this. Check out for a [simple implementation here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/). And you can find a bit more detailed [article here](http://www.lissaexplains.com/css3.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this.

```css
div#col2 {
  padding-left: 160px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
}
```

This relies on `#col1` coming before `#col2`, which might make it unusable.

This will not, but relies on `#col1` being the longer:

```css
#content {
  position: relative;   
}
div#col2 {
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
}

div#col1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

This'll keep the footer in place.

```css
div#footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use float:left on first column and float:right on the second column

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is for years ago, I provide this useful answer for any future reference and similar cases.

Putting `#col1` before `#col2` in markup, you may float it to the right, in case you have LTR lauout (if you have an RTL layout then float to the left) and give the other col `overflow: hidden`.

Note that the parent ( `#content` ) should have the `overflow: hidden` too:

```css
#content{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #cdeecd;
}

#content #col1{
  float: right;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eecdcd;
}

#content #col2{
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #cdcdee;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
     <div id="col1"></div>
     <div id="col2"></div>
</div>
```