# How can I lay out three divs in two columns without using tables?

Tags: html

I need the following layout of divs:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|           |           |
|   Div A   |           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
+-----------+   Div C   |
|           |           |
|    Div B  |           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I searched hard, but all I have found are lots of similar questions about placing divs in two columns (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748178/simple-2-column-div-layout) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144375/2-column-layout-in-css)). None seem to deal with this exact problem.

I've tried using `float:left` and `clear:both`, but I just can't get anywhere.

Obviously it can be achieved using tables, but isn't it bad practice to use tables for layout. Can it be done without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div id="topLeft" style="float:left; width:50%; height:200px">
</div>
<div id=topRight style="float:right; width:50%; height:400px">
</div>
<div id="bottomLeft" style="float:left; width:50%; width:200px">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't work at first, because I had got borders on the divs. But, when I reduced the width to 45%, it looked just right.

Comment: Never try to guess the best width of the containers in percentage when you have padding, margin or border. It'll work fine in the browser you optimize it but will most likely break in others. IE7 and IE8 are notoriously flawed at this. Instead add inner DIV tags that have border and padding if needed and leave the wrapper/container with 50% and border/padding/margin=0

Answer (score 1):

If they don't have to be in that order, this should work:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">    
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:200px;
}

#div1, #div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

#div3 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}

#div1 {
    background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#div3 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3UTcP/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <div id="AB-Wrapper" style="float:left;width:50%;">
        <div id="DivA">some content</div>
        <div id="DivB">some more content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="DivC" style="float:right;width:50%;">even more content</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"><!-- clearer --></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xREQK/